# graphql-tag/loader: Module build failed with GraphQLError: Syntax Error

Tags: vue.js, webpack, graphql, babeljs, graphql-tag

Weird issue I am facing. Using Vue-CLI3 `npm run serve`.

Have the following config:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    // GraphQL Loader
    config.module
      .rule('graphql')
      .test(/\.graphql$/)
      .use('graphql-tag/loader')
      .loader('graphql-tag/loader')
      .end();
  }
};
```

and one single `.graphql` file:

```
mutation AddOfficeMutation(
    $name: String
    $location: String
  ) {
    createOffice(
      input: {office: { name: $name, location: $location }}
    ) {
      office {
        id
        name
        location
      }
    }
  }
```

when running `npm run serve`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                                                                           1:11:08 PM

 error  in ./src/graphql/AddOfficeMutation.graphql

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/graphql-tag/loader.js):
GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Unexpected Name "var"
    at syntaxError (/Users/danroc/Dropbox/projects/tal-firebase/client-vue/node_modules/graphql/error/syntaxError.js:24:10)
    at unexpected (/Users/danroc/Dropbox/projects/tal-firebase/client-vue/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:1490:33)
    at parseDefinition (/Users/danroc/Dropbox/projects/tal-firebase/client-vue/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:153:9)
    at many (/Users/danroc/Dropbox/projects/tal-firebase/client-vue/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:1520:16)
    at parseDocument (/Users/danroc/Dropbox/projects/tal-firebase/client-vue/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:113:18)
    at parse (/Users/danroc/Dropbox/projects/tal-firebase/client-vue/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:48:10)
    at parseDocument (/Users/danroc/Dropbox/projects/tal-firebase/client-vue/node_modules/graphql-tag/src/index.js:129:16)
    at gql (/Users/danroc/Dropbox/projects/tal-firebase/client-vue/node_modules/graphql-tag/src/index.js:170:10)
    at Object.module.exports (/Users/danroc/Dropbox/projects/tal-firebase/client-vue/node_modules/graphql-tag/loader.js:44:18)

 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/AddOfficeForm.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& 29:0-69 59:18-35
 @ ./src/components/AddOfficeForm.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/components/AddOfficeForm.vue
 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/AddOfficeView.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/views/AddOfficeView.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/views/AddOfficeView.vue
 @ ./src/router/routes.js
 @ ./src/router/router-config.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client?http://192.168.0.99:8080/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

Using:

- "graphql": "^14.0.2"
- "graphql-tag": "^2.10.0"

I am slowly assuming this might be an error with my Babel or Vue config?
Anyone can shed some light on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using [vue-cli-plugin-apollo](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-cli-plugin-apollo)?

Comment: yes, I added it with `vue add apollo`

Comment: I think the plugin already is loading graphql-tag/loader and you are running it twice by having a custom webpack rule . Have you tried it without the custom rule and maybe renaming the file to .gql?

Comment: thanks, I think that was it. I recreated the project and did not add the rules to vue.config.js and it is working fine!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and it seemed that having 2 loaders make the crash.

I had installed `graphql-tag` and `webpack-graphql-loader` .

Try to uninstall every package that includes apollo or graphql and reinstall using `vue cli` again. `vue add apollo`. It worked for me.